# Proportional image: what size should my image be when creating @2x/@3x

Tags: ios, xcode

If I got an image that has a proportional width/height depending on the screen, on what dimensions should my image be based? Lets say the image is 100x100 on a iPhone 5s and 200x200 on a iPhone 6, should the image (@2x) be 200x200 or 400x400? The answer I read are all based on a fixed size.

Thanks.

Comment: the iphone 5s uses 2x resolution. if iphone 5s is 100*100, the iphone 7 plus is 150*150. (1x would be 50*50 here.)

Comment: But if I got a proportional width, the size increases on larger devices. What dimensions should I use to create that 2x resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an image that is proportionally scaled, you want to optimize the image for the largest point size.  High resolution images that are scaled down look better than low resolution images that are scaled up.

In your case, the largest point size is 200 x 200 points, so your @2x images would be 400 x 400 and your @3x images would be 600 x 600.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with images on iOS is with vectorials (ex: .pdf)

You add the image into your assets and on the right bar in "Scales" you chose : Single scale

The system chose the size for you